# Relation of breather and gradient soliton.

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, ricci-flow

As picture below , I am fuzzy with the red line.
As definition 1.5.1, assuming  $g_{ij}(t)$ is expanding breather,then for some $t_1<t_2 \text{ and }\alpha>0$,$\alpha g_{ij}(t)$ and $g_{ij}(t)$ are diffeomorphic. Then $(M,g_{t_1})$ and $(M,g_{t_2})$ are diffeomorphic. Then $\lambda(g_{ij}(t_1))=\lambda(g_{ij}(t_2))$.Then,expanding breather is a steady gradient soliton. And likely, shrink breather is steady gradient soliton.

The picture below is from 203rd page of this [paper](http://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.ajm/1154098947).

> [image]
>   [image]

Comment: It seems from the first paragraph you answered your question already. What exactly do you not understand?

Comment: @JohnMa I think according the picture above  ,no matter shrinking or expanding breather, they are a steady gradient soliton. If I'm right ,the (ii) of 1.5.4 is surplus .

Comment: I understand now. Is it true that $\lambda(\alpha g_{ij}(t)) = \lambda (g_{ij}(t))$? It seems that one has to use $\overline \lambda$ to deal with the case that $\alpha\neq 1$.

Comment: I know there are corresponding proof about $\alpha \ne 1$ in the next page. And I think $\lambda(\alpha g_{ij}(t)) = \lambda (g_{ij}(t))$, because $\lambda(g_{ij})$ is invariant under diffeomorphism. @JohnMa

Comment: Actually you only have $\alpha g_{ij}(t_1)$ and $g_{ij}(t_2)$ are up to a diffeomorphism, so $\lambda (\alpha g_{ij} (t_1)) = \lambda (g_{ij}(t_2))$, but you do not have $\lambda(g_{ij}(t_1)) = \lambda(\alpha g_{ij}(t_1))$ when $\alpha\neq 1$.

Comment: For $\alpha >0, \text{and },\alpha \ne 1$,$(M,\alpha g_{ij}(t_1))$ is not diffeomorphism with $(M,g_{ij}(t_1))$ ?  @JohnMa

Comment: You are not using the term "diffeomorphism" correctly. The authors means that $(M, \alpha g_{ij}(t_1))$ and $(M, g_{ij}(t_2))$ are the same up to a diffeomorphism, which means there is a diffeomorphism $\phi : M \to M$ so that $\phi^* (g_{ij}(t_2)) = \alpha g_{ij}(t_1)$.

Comment: Note that there is no diffeomorphism $\phi$ so that $\phi^* g = \alpha g$ if $M$ is compact and $\alpha \neq 1$ as $\phi$ should preserves the volume. That $\phi^* g = \alpha g$ will force $Vol(M) = \int \sqrt{g} dx_1\cdots dx_n = \int_M \alpha^{n/2} \sqrt g dx_1\cdots dx_n = \alpha^{n/2} Vol(M)$, which is nonsense.

Comment: @JohnMa I agree with you.It should be understanded by your way. Thanks very much.